# MySql.Data.dll в Unity

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, unity3d

Всем привет!

Я хочу подключить MySql.Data.dll для соеденения моей игры с MySql.

Я создаю папку Plugins и закидываю туда MySql.Data.dll, и мне выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/MySql.Data.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Google.Protobuf'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Zstandard.Net'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'K4os.Compression.LZ4.Streams'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'BouncyCastle.Crypto'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Ubiety.Dns.Core'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Renci.SshNet'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
```

Я пробовал импортировать другие dll и они прекрасно работают!

Comment: `MySql.Data.dll` зависит от других библиотек - они перечислены у вас в списке ошибок.

Comment: @aepot пробовал добавлять, появилось ещё больше ошибок. До этого, на чистом c# писал, добавлял одну MySql.data и всё работало

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/185594/

Comment: Если у вас игра будет сетевая, то лучше сделать сервер, который будет работать с БД, а игра с сервером может работать например через HTTP, а запросы для обмена клиент-сервер можно реализовать в формате JSON. К тому же сервер сможет защитить даные в БД от повреждения и в случае если они секретные - не дать к ним доступ.

Comment: Можно еще воспользоваться [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) для того чтобы установить нужную библиотеку из nuget пакета.

Comment: Или же можете просто создать обычный шарповый проект, добавить зависимость на MySql и скопировать нужные библиотеки после паблишинга

Comment: @SmorclRL спасибо, но нет, пробовал

Comment: @aepot в таком же случае нужно делать собственное api, а в этом, я к сожалению, не силён(

Comment: @aepot спасибо за статью на хабре, но не помогло

Comment: Это проще, чем вам кажется. К тому же тема большая и прикольная, будет полезна для общего развития, в сети полно гайдов и видео. Берите ASP.NET Core Web API и попробуйте сделать хотя-бы один метод - авторизацию, юзер вводит в юнити логин и пароль, а сервер игре отвечает, можно войти или нет, если можно, то отдает игре токен (рандомная цифробуквенная строка), который игра будет использовать для всех последующих запросов, а сервер будет по токену узнавать, что именно за юзер прислал запрос.

Comment: @Bulson нет даже импортировав через NuGetForUnity, у меня всеровно выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Такую же ошибку? Ничего не поменялось?

Comment: Да, такуеже ошибку, нечего не поменялось

Comment:  возможно, что прав @aepot и вам придется написать серверную часть ASP.NET Core Web API  и работать с базой через нее.

Comment: Скорее всего(((

Comment: Еще можно попробовать гугловый Firebase или Mongodb Atlas и там и там можно зарегистрироваться по гугловой учетке. Ищите на ютубчике, полно уроков как работать с этими базами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена!

Огромное спасибо @Bulson . Этот человек посоветовал плагин для Unity под названием [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity), импортировав через него него пакет MySql.Data мне наконец то удалось добиться соединение MySql базы с игрой